# How to use PCA with masked hyperspectral-Image?

Tags: python, pandas, image

So I have a masked HSI with 150 channels and would like to apply PCA on it, as one can see I have to drop na rows and then treat rest as input to algorithm. The problem comes in restoration, I still want to display my image.

```
def extract_pixels(image):
  q = image.reshape(image.shape[0], -1).transpose()
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=q)
  # df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data=y.ravel())], axis=1)
  df.columns = [f'band{i}' for i in range(1, 1+image.shape[0])]
  df.to_csv('Dataset.csv')
  return df

df = extract_pixels(img)
# df = df.dropna()

pca = PCA(n_components=8)
dt = pca.fit_transform(df.iloc[:, :-1].values)

q = pd.DataFrame(data=dt)
```

img.shape
(150, 11, 11)

q.shape (later it should be reshaped back to 11x11)
(78, 8)

So problem is loosing some pixels and how to deal with it.